# Cocos2d rotating sprite while moving with CCBezierBy

Tags: sprites, cocos2d, rotation

I've done my moving actions which consists of sequences of CCBezierBy. However I would like the sprite to rotate by following the direction of the movement (like an airplane). How sould I do this with cocos2d?

I've done the following to test this out.

```
    CCSprite *green = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy_green.png"];
    [green setPosition:ccp(50, 160)];
    [self addChild:green];

    ccBezierConfig bezier;
    bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(100, 200);
    bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(400, 200);
    bezier.endPosition = ccp(300,160);

    [green runAction:[CCAutoBezier actionWithDuration:4.0 bezier:bezier]];
```

In my subclass:

```
@interface CCAutoBezier : CCBezierBy

@end

@implementation CCAutoBezier

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime) t
{
    CGPoint oldpos=[self.target position];
    [super update:t];
    CGPoint newpos=[self.target position];

    float angle = atan2(newpos.y - oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x);
    [self.target setRotation: angle];
}

@end
```

However it rotating, but not following the path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a class dedicated to this purpose or not but you can simply implement your own. just inherit your class from CCBezierBy class and then in update function after applying what CCBezierBy by does change direction of airplane based on  movement generated bu CCBezierBy.

there might be some errors in this code(i'll be glad if you fix them), but this is showing how easy you can implement it!

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) t
{
    CGPoint oldpos=[target position];
    [super update:t];
    CCPoint newpos=[target position];

    float angle = atan2(-newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;
    [target setRotation: angle];
}
```

I'm not sure if this will help you but here is my code (though in c++ using cocos2d-x)

```
class mybezier : public CCBezierBy
{
public:
    static CCBezierBy* actionWithDuration(float t,ccBezierConfig k)
    {
        mybezier* b = new mybezier;
        b->CCBezierBy::initWithDuration(t,k);
        return b;
    }

    virtual void update(ccTime t)
    {
        CCPoint oldpos = getTarget()->getPosition();
        CCBezierBy::update(t);
        CCPoint newpos = getTarget()->getPosition();
        float angle = atan2(-newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;
        getTarget()->setRotation(angle);//*  180);
    }
};
```

and I'm calling this class using this lines:

```
ccBezierConfig x;
x.controlPoint_1 = CCPoint(CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().width / 2,0);
x.controlPoint_2 = CCPoint(0, CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize().height / 2);
x.endPosition = CCPoint(0,0);
pSprite->runAction(CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(mybezier::actionWithDuration(10,x)));
```

Comment: That update method, where do you call it? Or is it called automatically? I really don't like the idea of having to call update from its parent. It would be good if I just simply CCAction:[BezierSubclass ...] and this autorotates the sprite.

Comment: it's called automatically, you just have to change every CCBezier word in your game to CCBezierSubclass and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Hmm, its not even rotating the sprite.

Comment: did you also override init and alloc methods? I think the main problem is by calling `[CCBezierSubclass alloc]` you are getting a reference to `CCBezier class` since alloc is not override in inherited class.

Comment: What should I put in init and alloc method?

Comment: Nevermind, i had to convert to degrees before assigning it to the sprite!

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is completely fixed or not, but I can't give any more help! since I'm using c++ port of cocos2d and I've got no idea what could go wrong in obj-c!

Comment: What I have is running well however, depending on the next position it doesn't rotate good.

Comment: it seems `float angle = atan2(newpos.y - oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;` should be changed to `float angle = atan2(- newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;` and it will work correctly.

Comment: Yeah ok worked, need to rotate the image in photoshop and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

This works great, here it is in Objective-C for Cocos2d on iOS. Just use CCTBezierRotateTo instead of CCBezierTo. Same thing should work for CCBezierBy. My sprites rotate to follow the path given by bezierForward.

I call it like this:

```
id bezierForward = [CCTBezierRotateTo actionWithDuration:10.0 bezier:bezier];
[missileSprite runAction:bezierForward];
```

Here is the .h:

```
#import "CCActionInterval.h"
@interface CCTBezierRotateTo : CCBezierTo
@end
```

Here is the class:

```
@implementation CCTBezierRotateTo

-(CCBezierBy*) actionWithDuration :(float)t :(ccBezierConfig) k {
    CCTBezierRotateTo* r = [CCTBezierRotateTo actionWithDuration:t];
    return r;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)time {
    CGPoint oldpos = [[self target] position];
    [super update:time];
    CGPoint newpos = [[self target] position];
    float angle = atan2(-newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;
    angle += 90; // my sprites start pointing up
    [[self target] setRotation:angle];
    NSLog(@"oldpos %f,%f newpos %f,%f angle %f", oldpos.x, oldpos.y, newpos.x, newpos.y,  angle);
}
```