# Rotating object along bezier curve: not rotating enough?

Tags: c#, unity, rotation, curves, beziers

I tried to follow the instructions from the threads on the forum ([Cocos2d rotating sprite while moving with CCBezierBy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20527/cocos2d-rotating-sprite-while-moving-with-ccbezierby)) with Unity, in order to rotate my object as it moves along a bezier curve. But it does not rotate enough, the angle is too low, it goes up to 6 instead of 90 for example, as you can see on this image (the y eulerAngle is at 6, I would expect it to be around 90 with this curve) :

[image]

---

EDIT: here is the solution :

```
Vector3 v3 = newPos - oldPos;
v3.y = 0.0f;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v3);
```

---

Here is the code (in c# with Unity) : (I am comparing x and z to get the angle, and adding the angle to eulerAngles.y so that it rotates around the y axis)

```
void Update () {
        if ( Input.GetKey("d") ) start = true;
        if ( start ){
            myTime = Time.time;
            start = false;
        }
        float theTime = (Time.time - myTime) *0.5f;
        if ( theTime < 1 ) {
            car.position = Spline.Interp( myArray, theTime );//creates the bezier curve
            counterBezier += Time.deltaTime;

            //compare 2 positions after 0.1f
            if ( counterBezier > 0.1f ){
                counterBezier = 0;
                cbDone = false;
                newpos = car.position;
                float angle = Mathf.Atan2(newpos.z - oldpos.z, newpos.x - oldpos.x);
                angle += car.eulerAngles.y;             
                car.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,angle,0);
            }
            else if ( counterBezier > 0 && !cbDone ){
                oldpos = car.position;
                cbDone = true;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: It think you're mixing radians and degrees. The result of Mathf.Atan2 is radians. eulerAngles.y is degrees. Everything should be degrees.

Comment: @Calvin thanks, indeed you were right, but the object does not stop rotating with Rad2Deg. Finally it works fine with the code in my edit, thanks for your comment anyway!

Comment: Instead of editing the question to add the solution, just post a new answer and mark it as accepted.  You may need to wait a bit before you're allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution :

```
Vector3 v3 = newPos - oldPos;
v3.y = 0.0f;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v3);
```

Comment: One thing to point out is that `newPos - oldPos` is an approximation of the derivative; if you have a tightly curving bezier, it can be a _bad_ approximation. The exact derivative is calculable in the same way position is.

Comment: @DrewCummins "The exact derivative is calculable in the same way position is" - What does it mean?

Comment: It means that you calculate the position by evaluating the bezier function `B` at time `t`: `x = B(t)`. The derivative `d/dt B(t)` is the exact correct direction at time `t`. So instead of calculating the derivative as `v = B(t_now) - B(t_old)` like you are now, you calculate it as `v = d/dt B(t_now)`.