# How do I rotate a sprite with ccbezierTo in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d, cocos2d-x, transformation

In cocos2d-x, I move a sprite with `ccbezierTo` like this:

```
// use for ccbezierTo
bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 200, visibleSize.height/2 + 300);
bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 400, visibleSize.height/2 - 300);
bezier.endPosition = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 600,visibleSize.height/2);

bezier1.controlPoint_1 = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 800, visibleSize.height/2 + 300);
bezier1.controlPoint_2 = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 1000, visibleSize.height/2 - 300);
bezier1.endPosition = ccp(m_fish->getPositionX() + 1200,visibleSize.height/2);


bezierForward = CCBezierTo::create(6, bezier);
nextBezier = CCBezierTo::create (6,bezier1);

m_fish->runAction(CCSequence::create( bezierForward, nextBezier, NULL));
```

How can I make my sprite rotate while moving it with `CCBezierTo`?

Comment: This could help http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20527/cocos2d-rotating-sprite-while-moving-with-ccbezierby or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990443/rotating-a-sprite-on-a-bezier-curve-in-cocos2d

Comment: Thanks i solved, i use this code:   CGPoint oldpos = [[self target] position];
    [super update:time];
    CGPoint newpos = [[self target] position];
    float angle = atan2(-newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;
    angle += 90; // my sprites start pointing up
    [[self target] setRotation:angle];

Comment: Can you write it as an answer and mark it "accepted" please? It will be easier for people having the same problem to find an answer

Comment: Sure, i use this link http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20527/cocos2d-rotating-sprite-while-moving-with-ccbezierby

Comment: I mean, can you write an answer explaining how you solved it ? Not only a comment. You would then be able to mark your answer as "accepted" so people would know it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution on this site. Use this very useful code:

```
 CGPoint oldpos = [[self target] position];
    [super update:time];
    CGPoint newpos = [[self target] position];
    float angle = atan2(-newpos.y + oldpos.y, newpos.x - oldpos.x) * 180 / M_PI;
    angle += 90; // my sprites start pointing up
    [[self target] setRotation:angle];
```

and sprite can rotate when move with ccbezierTo.